# What are the real properties of an ordinary LED?

Tags: led, diodes

I would like to simulate a typical LED in MATLAB. However, I need the following info:

1. Internal resistance (in Ohms)
2. Internal capacity (in Farads)
3. Self-Inductance ( in Henries )

All of the values should be really small but they do matter in my simulation.

Comment: Internal inductance should just be that of the connections, I would guess 10 or20nH. The others I'm afraid will be more complicated. As it is a non-linear device the slope resistance will be current dependent and the capacitance will be voltage dependent.

Comment: "the real properties": Reality is much more complex than that; you might want to just actually list what you need to know "looking for detailed properties of an LED".

Comment: This is incredibly broad.  Like across an entire type of component!  There are so many types of LEDs, it isn't clear what you mean by an 'ordinary LED'

Comment: Most established applications for LEDs don't require this level of characterization (and when they are needed, like in 50 Mb/s communications, they might be kept proprietary). If you really need it for what you're trying to design, you might have to get samples of some likely candidate parts and a network analyzer and develop your own models.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Internal resistance (in Ohms)

It's a Diode. Diodes don't have linear relation between Voltage and current, so they don't have a constant resistance, but a exponentional V/I characteristic. **Diodes are non-ohmic.**

Sometimes you model this behaviour as differential resistance \$r\$ instead of the fixed resistance of a resistor, \$R\$, subject to change over voltage:

\$r = \frac{dU}{dI}\$

Of course, there's also added static resistance due to copper losses and classical semiconductor (non-junction) resistance. It should be relatively small for usual LEDs during usage.

Notice that exponential relation between U and I implies that in reverse bias, a Diode pretty much isolates (aside from a minimal leakage current).

> 2. Internal capacity (in Farads)

The capacitance of a diode depends on a lot of factors, mainly on voltage applied over its semiconductor junction. In fact, semiconductor elements are often used as adjustable capacitors by applying a variable bias voltage.

> 3. Self-Inductance ( in Henries )

Well, like any device, the leads of an LED have inductivity. It usually doesn't matter much; you just don't feed a Gigahertz signal into an LED (different things apply for RF diodes!)

A lot of these numbers (aside from the inductance, which typically is dominated by the way you connect the LED to your circuit) should be available as diagrams in your specific LED's datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You would like to use a Simulink model of diode, described here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/diode.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

And as I see You don't properly understand properties of that model and its relation to real diode.

\$R_{on}\$ is not an "internal resistance" of diode, but resistance in "on" state - in reality diode have dynamic resistance, it changes with current flowing through it. In case of Simulink You should treat \$R_{on}\$ as the sum of (constant) resistance of leads and dynamic resistance at linear region of V/I characteristics at forward conducting state.

\$L_{on}\$ - inductance of the diode is mainly an inductance of its leads.

In Simulink model there is no internal capacitance of a diode (in reality diode capacitance is linked mainly with junction capacitance).